# Inside Listview Edit and delete buttons are displaying for each row in android

Tags: android, dynamic

I am developing an android application in which I have one ListView. I have to add 2 buttons with each row in ListView. These 2 buttons are Add and Delete. 
But I am unable to display these edit and delete buttons.

Add.java describes that if the response is successful and then display a list of the names in listview. In the same way I want to display edit and delete button to the each row of the listview

Inside listview edit and delete buttons are not displaying for each row for the below code.

Add.java:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                            String Status = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));
                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                ArrayList<itemModel> arrayList1;
                                arrayList1=arrayList;
                                String id;
                               // String name[]={} ;

                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length ();i++) {
                                    name=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");

                                    itemModel itemmodel = new itemModel();
                                    itemmodel.setName(name);
                                    arrayList1.add (itemmodel);

                                }

                                //MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(arrayList1, this);
                                //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                //adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                                MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity (), arrayList1);
                               // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }
```

Comment: Use RecylerView as listview is not recommended in android now, also try using ArrayAdapter for adapter

Comment: Check my whole updated answer

Comment: @SumitShukla Please check my updated question

Comment: Why are you using two adapters?

Comment: @SumitShukla one for displaying listview names and another for edit and buttons

Comment: @SumitShukla See my edited comment

Comment: You can combine both adapters in one

Answer (score 0):

You need to add scrollview to main xml .i.e; where you mention listview in that xml you need to add scrollview . In that scrollview you need to add listview ,edit text and button.

If you scrolls up then the edittext and button will visible .

Answer (score 0):

You can [see here](https://11zon.com/android/android_customlistview.php).

```
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, arrayList.get(position).getName() + " Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```